# Start timer interval without using useEffect hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to start a timer interval in react native without using useEffect hook, in  y case I want to start a timer when a promise resolves and change a state variable each second, how can I do this without using useEffect hook?

i tried this:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
        
     setCounter(counter+1)
    
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  },
  [] // empty dependency array
);
```

And while it works I need to start the timer calling it from a normal function and not a hook.

Comment: Why without `useEffect` whereas it's the proper way do to it?

Answer (score 3):

Any side effects (including starting a timer) should not belong to the main body of the component function. Instead, it is best to delegate these things to a `useEffect()` hook.

If I understood your question correctly, you can still start that timer inside a hook, simply call the normal function inside.

E.g. it can be this simple if your normal function already returns a function to clean itself:

```js
useEffect(() => startTimer(setCounterCallback), [])
```

Oh, and if the plan is to start it after a promise resolves, *also* wrap that async function inside the same `useEffect()`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const promise = Promise.resolve();
  promise.then(() => startTimer(setCounterCallback));
}, []);
```